# Linux PAM: add specific lib to Makefile and compile a single module

Tags: centos, compiling, pam

I am dealing with the development of a custom PAM module for a CentOS7 system.
As starting point, I'd like to use the project **[linux-pam](https://fedorahosted.org/linux-pam/)**, specifically:

- compiling only the `pam_permit` module;
- adding as dependency also `libcurl`, adding the flag `-lcurl`.

Note that whole `linux-pam` project has to be configured, then compiled and installed, but I didn't find an option in order to select only a single module, and also I didn't point out how to properly edit the Makefile in order to add also CURL lib.

If possible, could someone give me some suggestions?